# MVC5 how to iterate through an azure active directory user group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory

I've managed to get the group I want from AAD by using

```
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
              async () => await GetTokenForApplication());

        // use the token for querying the graph to get the user details

        var result = await activeDirectoryClient.Groups.Where(u => u.DisplayName.Equals("myGroupName")).ExecuteAsync();
```

But I'm not sure how to iterate through the group I got and add all the users from that group into a list.

Comment: What do you mean? what is the type of result? Isn't it some type of collection?

Comment: I would create a User class that represents the results returned from the ActiveDirectoryClient then map that to the result set such as. List<User> users = await activeDirectoryClient.Groups.Where(u => u.DisplayName.Equals("myGroupName")).ExecuteAsync(); Then iterate through the list. foreach(User result in users){ //do something here }

Comment: @Waragi that doesn't work because result returns an IGroup type and it's just a group so you cant map it to a User type

Comment: @CodingYoshi the type is IGroup, and I want to go into that group to iterate through all the users in that group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
List<IGroup> groups = result.CurrentPage.ToList();
foreach (IGroup group in groups)
{
    // do whatever you need to
}
```

**EDIT**

> does IGroup have and property that allows me to get the users in that group such as members

Yes it does but you will need to explicitly ask for it to be expanded. Here is how to get all the users for the group:

```
var groups = await activeDirectoryClient.Groups
    .Where(g => g.DisplayName == groupName).Expand(g => g.Members)
    .ExecuteAsync();

var usersForGroup = new List<User>();
foreach(IGroup thisGroup in groups)
{
    do
    {
        var thisGroupUsers = 
            thisGroup.Members.CurrentPage.Select(m => m as User)).Where(u => u != null);
        allUsers.AddRange(thisGroupUsers);

        // get next page asynchronously
        await thisGroup.Members.GetNextPageAsync();
    } while(thisGroup.Members.MorePagesAvailable)

}
```

Comment: how will that work? there will only be 1 item in groups which is the group I queried for. And there isn't any attributes for IGroup that allows me to go inside the group and look at the users inside the group

Comment: Did you try the code? Although you queried for one group, you used `Where` which could possibly return many. If there is just one, the loop will run just once. If you are sure it should return only one,  then change your query and use `First` or use `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: does IGroup have and property that allows me to get the users in that group such as `members` mentioned by @RasmusW below. Because right now the code returns that `Members = 0` despite all the other properties being displayed correctly such as `displayName` and `objectId`

Comment: thanks for the edit, it worked. However it only gives me the users on the first page of the group.

I tried using `while(groups != null){ groups = await groups.GetNextPageAsync()}` but it doesn't go to the next page/list of users, can you help me with this one as well.

Comment: because right now the expand method somehow only gets the first 20 members of the group but I have way more than that and I want to get all of them, is there a way of doing this? I was thinking of using `GetNextPageAsync()` but I can't seem to be able to put that anywhere

Comment: You have to request the next page on the `Members`. Please see edit. Keep in mind I am not testing this code so you may need to adjust it.

Comment: I've found a different example that helped with the issue, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the group's object ID, you can get the direct members using this URL in the graph API:

`https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/{object_id}/$links/members?api-version`

The `IGroup` result you get in your code (e.g. using `result.First()`), does contain a `Members` property, which you can use to loop through the members.

You can use an `IGroupFetcher` to retrieve group members:

```
var group = await adClient.Groups.Where(g => g.ObjectId == groupObjectId).ExecuteSingleAsync();
IGroupFetcher groupfetcher = (Group)group;
var membersResult = await groupfetcher.Members.ExecuteAsync();

var more = true;
while (more)
{
    foreach (var member in membersResult.CurrentPage) 
    {
    //... remember to handle that members can be other groups
    }
    if (!membersResult.MorePagesAvailable)
    {
        more = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // get next page in results
        membersResult = await membersResult.GetNextPageAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a weird error as the member property is returning 0 members, however the other properties are still correct such as objectId and displayName